# Scripts loaded through ajax don't send the post data to themselves properly?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

So the structure is:

index.php
loads /index.php#ajax/landing.php

landing.php has a form, the form data is sent as post request (Tamper data show the POST data being sent), but `var_dump($_POST);` in landing.php is showing empty. I'm guessing because of the way the script is loaded the post data must be being sent to index.php and must not be accessible to landing.php?

is there a work around for this?

I've considered the possibility of using ajax to send the post data and show the result in a div but i'm not that good with it and don't really understand what i'm doing,

so in my scenario here is what i'm trying to do:

```
<form name="search_form" id="search_form" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="search" id="search" />
<input type="submit" name="submit_search_form" id="submit_search_form" value="search" />
</form>

<div id="search_results">

</div>
```

How would I make this send a POST request to `/php/search.php` then put the results of what the script does with the post data into the search results div?

Any ideas / help would be greatly appreciated. 
note i'm asking for POST as GET/query strings can be accessed by the page, but isn't appropriate for other tasks like changing passwords so although in the scenario i've mentioned would be fine as a GET request, I need to figure out a way to get POST working regardless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use something like this (which requires jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function() { // When the document is completely loaded this function runs
    $('form').unbind('submit').bind('submit', function(event) { // catch the pressing of enter and catch submit action. Makes sure the form does not get posted the normal way
        if (event.keyCode == 13) { // if enter is pressed
            return false;
        }
        pageRetrieve($(this).attr('action')+"?"+$(this).serialize(), 'POST'); // send this data to the function that sends the post
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});

function pageRetrieve(href, sType) { // this function send the data to the server
    sType = (typeof sType === "undefined") ? "GET" : sType; // if 'POST' is not set in the previous function, set it to GET
    $.ajax({ // function to send the data to the server
        url: href, // the url to send it to
        type: sType, // the type (post/get)
        success: function (data) { // when the server responds successful 
            $('#search_results').html(data); // put the data in your div
        },
        error: function () { // if call to server is not correct (eg wrong url)
            alert("error");
        }
    });
}
```

This just posts data to the specified url in the form.

Comment: I see the success but i'm not all that familiar with this type of programming. what will `console.log(data)` do? and i've saw something that alows you to put the output of the script that was sent the data to be inserted into an existing div by id?

Comment: console.log outputs the the data it has to your browser console (sort of error log). I changed it to send the data to your div

Comment: Thank you, I'm assuming I have permission to use your code? And will the POST requests be the same as traditional ones? meaning will for search.php what receives the request, would the variables be accessible using the traditional `$_POST['search']`?

Comment: for url do i put the full url / file path or just file path? and also does replace the href or add after the ,?

Comment: A full url is always recommended (in your entire code base), but a a path like "submit.php (or whatever the name of your file) will do too.

Comment: the "?" thing. This: $(this).serialize() gets all the inputs of the form (if they have a "name") and makes a nice post url of it. So it's automatic